# T-SQL is interpreting "less than" as "less than or equal to"

Tags: t-sql

This is a section of an SQL query which is designed to identify if the "Nelson Rules" (see Statistical Process Control) are triggered for a particular series.

In this section, the result "six (or more) points continually increasing or decreasing" is being returned when the current and previous five values are 34, 33, 30, 27, 27, 26, 26 and 24.

This is not what I intended, and suggests to me that T-SQL is interpreting "less than" signs as "less than or equal to".

```
case when (TRUCKS<(lag(Trucks,1) over (order by [date]))     and (lag(Trucks,1) over (order by [date]) < lag(Trucks,2) over (order by [date]))  
        and (lag(Trucks,2) over (order by [date]) < lag(Trucks,3) over (order by [date])) and (lag(Trucks,3) over (order by [date]) < lag(Trucks,4) over (order by [date]))
        and (lag(Trucks,4) over (order by [date]) < lag(Trucks,5) over (order by [date])))

        OR

        (TRUCKS>(lag(Trucks,1) over (order by [date]))   and (lag(Trucks,1) over (order by [date]) > lag(Trucks,2) over (order by [date]))  
        and (lag(Trucks,2) over (order by [date]) > lag(Trucks,3) over (order by [date])) and (lag(Trucks,3) over (order by [date]) > lag(Trucks,4) over (order by [date]))
        and (lag(Trucks,4) over (order by [date]) > lag(Trucks,5) over (order by [date])))

        THEN 'Six (or more) points continually increasing or decreasing'

        else null end as Rule_Three
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample set of data for the values within `Trucks` and `Date`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a quick test of your query using the values that you have provided. I get the results that you were expecting (i.e. null for all rows).

Here is a short test case.

First I created a table with a Trucks column and a date column:

```
USE [YourDatabase]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TrucksTable](
    [Trucks] [int] NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I then inserted the values that you've mentioned in your question:

```
INSERT INTO TrucksTable (Trucks, [date])
VALUES
(34, '2017-06-25'),
(33, '2017-06-24'),
(30, '2017-06-23'),
(27, '2017-06-22'),
(27, '2017-06-21'),
(26, '2017-06-20'),
(26, '2017-06-19'),
(24, '2017-06-18')
```

And at last I executed this query against my newly created table to test your expression:

```
SELECT
    Trucks,
    [date],
    lag(Trucks,1) over (order by [date]) AS Lag1,
    lag(Trucks,2) over (order by [date]) AS Lag2,
    lag(Trucks,3) over (order by [date]) AS Lag3,
    lag(Trucks,4) over (order by [date]) AS Lag4,
    lag(Trucks,5) over (order by [date]) AS Lag5,
    CASE 
        WHEN (TRUCKS<(lag(Trucks,1) over (order by [date])) 
            and (lag(Trucks,1) over (order by [date]) < lag(Trucks,2) over (order by [date]))  
            and (lag(Trucks,2) over (order by [date]) < lag(Trucks,3) over (order by [date])) 
            and (lag(Trucks,3) over (order by [date]) < lag(Trucks,4) over (order by [date]))
            and (lag(Trucks,4) over (order by [date]) < lag(Trucks,5) over (order by [date])))
            OR
            (TRUCKS>(lag(Trucks,1) over (order by [date]))   
            and (lag(Trucks,1) over (order by [date]) > lag(Trucks,2) over (order by [date]))  
            and (lag(Trucks,2) over (order by [date]) > lag(Trucks,3) over (order by [date])) 
            and (lag(Trucks,3) over (order by [date]) > lag(Trucks,4) over (order by [date]))
            and (lag(Trucks,4) over (order by [date]) > lag(Trucks,5) over (order by [date])))
    THEN 'Six (or more) points continually increasing or decreasing'
    ELSE NULL END AS Rule_Three
FROM TrucksTable
```

The result is this:
[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Wlt.png)

Since you are getting a different result, my best guess it that your [Trucks] column is of an approximate number data type such as a float or real. I suggest that you check the data type of your [Trucks] column to see whether this is the case.